# Excel vba - command depending on previous command

Tags: variables, triggers, command

Firstly I am new to vba, and in the course of learning have learned a ton from searching this site. Unfortunately this time no success.

I do not know how to tackle this.

My "home" userform has 6 command buttons with no caption to them (empty).

On pressing any one of these, a "names" userform is opened, with 10 command buttons - each is captioned with a different persons name.

I want the chosen perdons name assigned to the caption of the command button that triggered "names" to appear.

On each form I have placed a label. This label's caption changes to the caption of tge command button clicked.

Options I have considered:
1. Multiple multiple IF statements
2. Assigning variables - cant figure out what to assign

I can post my code, but as i do not know where to begin I don't think it would be to much use.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out!

Made a module with if statments.

Called it from "names" every time a name is chosen.

By doing this no need for writing the same code over again.